# faces won't show up

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

when I visit the following page
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

and input http://www.facebook.com/tommckinneyvocalstudios as the facebook page URL none of the profile faces for users who have liked the page are showing up. When I log into my account they do appear.

However, when I input the following facebook page URL /burtsbees as an example, the profile faces show up just fine without me logging in or out. What could be causing this issue? Why would this work for one URL and not the other?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. I would file a ticket with bug tracker - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Sorry for this question, as I'm sure it is obvious but how do I file a new bug? I do not see a form on this page. Only a search box to search currently open or resolved bugs. Thanks.

Comment: If you start typing some text inside the Search box, it will try to match if there were other similar bugs filed..if not, it will show you an option to create a new bug report.